# Pass textbox value from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am building a web application where I need the values of my textbox passed to controller on button click. And according to the user role, I need to redirect to different pages. Following is my code.

View:

```
@model namespace.ViewModels.LoginVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h1>User Login</h1>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <br />
    <div style="background-color: skyblue; width: 50%">
        <div style="padding-left: 1em">
            <div class="display-label" style="font-size: large">
                Enter User Info<br />
                <br />
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.empID)</div>
                <div class="editor-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.empID)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.empID)
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
}
```

Controller:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login() 
    {
        MySQL msql = new MySQL();            
        // var empID= *how do I get empID on submit from View?* ;
        var role = msql.Select("Select `role` from empDB where `eID` = '" + empID+ "'");
        //if(role = "admin") { return RedirectToAction("Home"); }
        //else {return View(); }            
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class LoginVM
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
    [DisplayName("empID")]
    public int empID{ get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Where do you stuck?

Comment: I could not get the textbox value to my controller on button click.

Comment: Add `LoginVM model` to your `Login` action method then use `model.empID`

Comment: By add I mean as a method parameter

Comment: `public ActionResult Login(LoginVM model) { var empID = model.empID; ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the view model as a parameter for your Post action

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginVM model) 
    {
        MySQL msql = new MySQL();            
        // var empID= *how do I get empID on submit from View?* ;
        var role = msql.Select("Select `role` from empDB where `eID` = '" + model.empID + "'");
        //if(role = "admin") { return RedirectToAction("Home"); }
        //else {return View(); }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a form field value on form submit, you may add a parameter with the same name as of the input field, to the action method to which the form is submitting.

Since your input field name attribute value is `"empID"`(*Check the view source of the page*), you can add a param to your method with same name

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(int empID) 
{ 
    //Check the value of empID parameter. 
   // For you to understand, I replaced your code with a line 
   // which basicaly return the value of this parameter value back
   //  to the client with a string "Received".

    return Content("Received "+  empID);        
}
```

Now I see you have a view model with a property with the name same as the parameter we added. In that case you can use that class as the parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginVM model) 
{ 
    //Check the value of model.empID parameter value.
    return Content("Received "+  model.empID);        
}
```

When the form is submitted, the model binder will map the posted form data to the properties of `LoginVM` class object.